# Why bot file missing from azure web app bot?

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, azure-bot-service

I make my web app bot in azure, then I download my code to work in that code with visual studio. when I decided to run that code, I realize it didnt come with a `.bot` file. So I dont have any way to test it in bot emulator.

I try to create my .bot but it's giving a error Post 500, or Internel Error

```
 {
      "name": "CoreBot",
      "services": [
        {
          "type": "endpoint",
          "name": "development",
          "endpoint": "http://localhost:3978/api/messages",
          "appId": "",
          "appPassword": "",
          "id": "1"
        },
        {
          "type": "endpoint",
          "name": "production",
          "endpoint": "https://CoreBot.azurewebsites.net/api/messages",
          "appId": "<YOUR APP ID>",
          "appPassword": "<YOUR APP PASSWORD>",
          "id": "2"
        }
      ],
      "padlock": "",
      "version": "2.0"
    }
```

Comment: Did you tried to debug?

Comment: yes,
The only thing i did was create, download and open in visual studio. i didnt have opportunity to make bugs.

Comment: The bot trying to configure it self from file or environment variable or something like this. If one of them not configured as same as the server, your local project will failed. So please debug and tell us where your bot is fail

Comment: Which language you write?

Comment: my language is C#

Comment: Please add tag for `C#` or `ASP.NET` or Core or something

Comment: And until you research a bit more about your Internal Server Error, we can just guess the answer, and we not guessing here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prior to the Bot Framework SDK 4.3 release, Microsoft Bot Framework offered the .bot file as a mechanism to manage resources. However, going forward it is recommended that you use appsettings.json for managing these resources as the .bot file has been deprecated. So the newer Echo and Basic bots don't have  .bot files.

If you want to test your downloaded bot code with the Emulator, then you can follow these steps:

- Debug the code on Visual Studio and it will open up a new window(localhost:3978) displaying the bot's name stating that the bot is ready.
- Open the Bot Framework Emulator (make sure you have the latest version).
- Click on the **Open Bot** option.
- Add the Bot URL(http://localhost:3978/api/messages) and click Connect(leave the App ID and App password blank).
- Send a message to your bot to test its features.

Make sure you remove the App Id and App password from your appsettings.json file for local testing. You can refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-file-basics?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp) for further clarification on how to manage bot resources.